# NoClassDefFoundError when using executions in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, noclassdeffounderror

**Update**

Based on the comments of others and my own tests, this appears to only be a problem with Maven 3.1.1 - I've [logged a bug with codehaus](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5543)

---

*I've created the smallest maven POM file I can to highlight the problem (see below)*.

I'm using an email server plugin (for integration testing).  I can launch the plugin no problem:

```
mvn emailserver:run
[INFO] --- emailserver-maven-plugin:1.1.1:run (default-cli) @ project ---
[INFO] Starting Greenmail mail server...
[INFO] Started Greenmail mail server
[INFO] Waiting for command from client
```

However, I have configured the plugin to run before the `integration-test` lifecycle.  When run this way, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
mvn integration-test
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/icegreen/greenmail/util/ServerSetup
```

When I execute maven with `-X` to see what's happening, in both cases it shows the same dependency tree as far as I can see, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why I'm getting an exception which it's launched through lifecycle phases.  Hopefully someone can help!

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Test Project</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.btmatthews.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>emailserver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <monitorKey>emailserver</monitorKey>
                    <monitorPort>10025</monitorPort>
                    <serverName>greenmail</serverName>
                    <portOffset>13000</portOffset>
                    <useSSL>false</useSSL>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-mail</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <daemon>true</daemon>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-mail</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Maven information:

```
> mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 16:22:22+0100)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_IE, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-13-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: I've maven install'ed it as is without errors... Running `mvn integration-test` worked as well, without the server being stopped obviously.

Comment: @Vic what does `mvn -v` give you?

Comment: Mvn 3.0.4 with Java 1.6.38, actually... Running with Java 1.7.25 works as well

Comment: Running `mvn integration-test` successfully builds for me, too. There is no daemon running afterwards, though, as far as I can see. I’m using Maven 3.0.4 and Java 1.7.0_25.

Comment: @Chriki so you didn't get an exception? I deleted my entire repo and retried just to be sure - same exception for me :(

Comment: @JohnFarrelly No, I don’t get any exceptions. It also appears that Maven has downloaded at least all `com.btmatthews.*` and `com.icegreen.*` dependencies for the first time a few minutes ago; so I should be using the same versions that you do.

Comment: @Chriki what version of maven are you running?

Comment: @Vic Hmm. I downloaded 3.0.5 and it also worked for me - so it must be a maven 3.1.1 problem...

Comment: @JohnFarrelly Maven documentation for 3.1 states "The significant change in Eclipse Aether with respect to API changes and package relocation will likely cause issues with plugins that directly depend on Aether.", maybe it is the case

Comment: I am the developer of that plugin and can confirm that it does not have a direct dependency on Aether. I've just successfully tested your POM with Maven 3.1.1 and Java 8. Can you confirm what version of the plugin you were using? Earlier versions of the plugin had a race condition during start-up. But that should have been fixed in version 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the class is present in the classpath at Compile time, but it doesn't exist in the classpath at Runtime.

So clean the project through eclipse, .class files are again will regenerate. Run the maven project again with help of Maven